# Use Angular /typsecript correctly to fill an array with selected objects

Tags: angular, typescript

Iv got an angular app reading json resource from spring-boot rest api(collection of simple player objects- id,name,position,value...) .... i have a button with each simply displayed object on UI, and I simply want to store each object in array when user clicks BUY button on component.html....i need to use my component.ts file, and i, being new to typescript, am unsure how to link the html method call to the .ts logic page...

any help much appreciated guys....this is just stage two of my basic fantasy footie type app where the list(arraylist if i was in java) will represent the users selected players to buy/ their custom team.....

COMPONENT.HTML:
'

```
     <ul *ngIf="Ballers">

      <li *ngFor="let player of Ballers">
        <p class="name">{{player.name}}</p>
        <p class="position">{{player.position}}</p>
        <p class="value">£{{player.value}} m</p>
        <button class="buyButton" on-click="buyThisPlayer()">Add to Squad</button>
     </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

COMPONENT.TS:

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'app-player-list',
    templateUrl: './playerList.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./playerList.component.scss']
 })
export class PlayerListComponent implements OnInit {

  Ballers: Object;
 // let selectedKickers=[] ;   //to declare my empty array???

   constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.httpService.getPlayers().subscribe(data => {
        this.Ballers = data;
        console.log(this.Ballers);
      })
  }

  buyThisPlayer(){
   selectedKickers.push(this); // this seems the only way to pinpoint my object to add???
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you're just interested in the click handler, you can pass the player in the method and bind to it like this:

```html
<button class="buyButton" (click)="buyThisPlayer(player)">Add to Squad</button>
```

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-player-list',
    templateUrl: './playerList.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./playerList.component.scss']
 })
export class PlayerListComponent implements OnInit {

  Ballers: any;
  selectedPlayers: any[] = [];

   constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.httpService.getPlayers().subscribe(data => {
        this.Ballers = data;
        console.log(this.Ballers);
      })
  }

  buyThisPlayer(player){
   this.selectedKickers.push(player);
  }
```

There are additional recommendations i'd suggest (going deeper into angular best practices). Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: Cheers thats perfect it gets me to the next stepping stone.....now to hook my selected players list back into my api and make a database entry......onwards and upwards...